# PHP foreach loop different arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array which I am looping with foreach and then within this loop I am looping another array. I display the result but I get all values from the second array within each loop of the first....

So if I have 3 items from 1st array looping at 1st foreach will be displayed ok but in the part of the 2nd foreach, I will have repeated data from 2nd array, instead of single.

Can you please assist, drive my thinking? Thank you

```
    "description": {
        "EN": {
            "headline": "artment in Malmö city",
            "summary": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum " 
        },
        "DA": {
            "headline": "3 værelses lejlighed i Malmø by",
            "summary": "Lorem Ipsum er simpelthen dummy tekst af t",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum er simpelthen " 
        },
```

Comment: Code maybe?????

Comment: It easier for us to understand if you give a sample data of the array and the loop you've done.

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: Please start with reading [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

it is very obvious that 2nd foreach loop will get full executed on every execution of 1st foreach loop